# Unable to Install PG on macOS after upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Postgres server is running properly. But when I tried to install `gem pg` then I'm getting following error:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
/Users/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby -I /Users/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20201109-14709-1vq5069.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes
checking for PQsetSingleRowMode()... yes
checking for PQconninfo()... yes
checking for PQsslAttribute()... yes
checking for PQresultVerboseErrorMessage()... yes
checking for PQencryptPasswordConn()... yes
checking for PQresultMemorySize()... yes
checking for timegm()... yes
checking for rb_gc_adjust_memory_usage()... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for C99 variable length arrays... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling gvl_wrappers.c
compiling pg.c
compiling pg_binary_decoder.c
compiling pg_binary_encoder.c
compiling pg_coder.c
pg_coder.c:216:34: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        res = this->dec_func(this, val, RSTRING_LEN(argv[0]), tuple, field, ENCODING_GET(argv[0]));
              ~~~~                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1000:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:996:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pg_coder.c:216:34: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        res = this->dec_func(this, val, RSTRING_LEN(argv[0]), tuple, field, ENCODING_GET(argv[0]));
              ~~~~                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1001:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
2 warnings generated.
compiling pg_connection.c
compiling pg_copy_coder.c
pg_copy_coder.c:228:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                        strlen = RSTRING_LEN(subint);
                                               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1000:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:996:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pg_copy_coder.c:228:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                        strlen = RSTRING_LEN(subint);
                                               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1001:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
pg_copy_coder.c:534:23: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                input_len = end_ptr - start_ptr;
                          ~ ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
3 warnings generated.
compiling pg_errors.c
compiling pg_record_coder.c
pg_record_coder.c:196:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                        strlen = RSTRING_LEN(subint);
                                               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1000:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:996:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pg_record_coder.c:196:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                        strlen = RSTRING_LEN(subint);
                                               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1001:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
2 warnings generated.
compiling pg_result.c
compiling pg_text_decoder.c
compiling pg_text_encoder.c
pg_text_encoder.c:194:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                        len = out - start;
                            ~ ~~~~^~~~~~~
pg_text_encoder.c:406:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                return optr - out;
                ~~~~~~ ~~~~~^~~~~
pg_text_encoder.c:410:12: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                return 2 + RSTRING_LEN(*intermediate) * 2;
                ~~~~~~ ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pg_text_encoder.c:617:13: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        nr_elems = RARRAY_LEN(value);
                 ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1058:23: note: expanded from macro 'RARRAY_LEN'
#define RARRAY_LEN(a) rb_array_len(a)
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
4 warnings generated.
compiling pg_tuple.c
pg_tuple.c:482:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        num_fields = RARRAY_LEN(values);
                   ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1058:23: note: expanded from macro 'RARRAY_LEN'
#define RARRAY_LEN(a) rb_array_len(a)
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
compiling pg_type_map.c
compiling pg_type_map_all_strings.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_class.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_column.c
pg_type_map_by_column.c:161:52: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        return dec_func( p_coder, RSTRING_PTR(field_str), RSTRING_LEN(field_str), 0, fieldno, enc_idx );
               ~~~~~~~~                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1000:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:996:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pg_type_map_by_column.c:161:52: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        return dec_func( p_coder, RSTRING_PTR(field_str), RSTRING_LEN(field_str), 0, fieldno, enc_idx );
               ~~~~~~~~                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1001:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
pg_type_map_by_column.c:230:17: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        conv_ary_len = RARRAY_LEN(conv_ary);
                     ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1058:23: note: expanded from macro 'RARRAY_LEN'
#define RARRAY_LEN(a) rb_array_len(a)
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
3 warnings generated.
compiling pg_type_map_by_mri_type.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_oid.c
compiling pg_type_map_in_ruby.c
compiling pg_util.c
pg_util.c:119:24: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        return (char*)out_ptr - out;
        ~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
1 warning generated.
linking shared-object pg_ext.bundle

current directory: /Users/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
make "DESTDIR=" install
make: /usr/local/opt/coreutils/bin/gmkdir: No such file or directory
make: *** [.sitearchdir.time] Error 1

make install failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.2.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/puneet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.6.0/pg-1.2.3/gem_make.out
```

Ruby version 2.6.3
Rails version 6.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by installing `coreutils` library.

Command to run on macOS:

`brew install coreutils`